# Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x^{4}}=\infty $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Please check my proof :)

We suppose that we are given $M\gt0$

we must find $\delta $ that $0<|x-0|<\delta \rightarrow \frac{1}{x^{4}}>M$

$$\frac{1}{x^{4}}>M$$

$$\frac{1}{M}>x^{4}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{M}}>x$$

Choose $\delta =\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{M}}$

Then $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{M}}>x\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x}>\sqrt[4]{M}$

Then, limit is $\infty $

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @Fourier, I post a formal proof for your reference and to others like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ideas are all correct. For future readers, let me reconstruct a formal proof.

Let $M>0$. Then we take  $\delta=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{M}}>0$. If $0<|x-0|<\delta$, then this means that $0<x<\delta$ implying $\frac{1}{x}>\frac{1}{\delta}$ ans so
$$\frac{1}{x^4}>\frac{1}{\delta^4}=M.$$
Thus, we get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

It is all correct!

And good luck for future proofs.

Comment: "Fire" proofs? Are they lit? 

Comment: And this is not an answer. This can better be a comment. But..

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add comments,when I reach 50,then I can do which is better for this site :)